# Keep physics object upright using engines placed on it

Tags: physics

So, I'm writing an auto-pilot, sorta, for a 3D physics object.

The player is allowed to place as many engines as they wish, wherever they wish. The auto-pilot is then supposed to keep this object upright using the engines, control each engine's thrust amount 0-100%. So if it's tilting to the right, it should fire all engines to the right a bit more. If it's tilting forward, but only slightly to the right, all engines in the direction it's tilting should fire more, so the object gets upright again.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: " If it's tilting forward, but only slightly to the right, all engines in the exact opposite direction should fire more." - This is unclear: do you want the left-rear engines to fire more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. determine motors usage

   - you have to make list for what your motors will be used
   - so divide all motors to groups by its direction
   - you should have motors for left,right,up,down,forward,backward
   - the problem is you can missing some ... in that case you are screwed and cant complete the task
   - the group sorting is not easy for non axis aligned arbitrary motors
   - to simplify this just do the dot product of motor direction and group direction
   - and the maximal values are belonging to motors of that group
   - the minimal values (negative) are belonging to opposite direction
   - so tag each motor with group
   - and try to select them so each group has at least one motor
2. control

   - well just use any type of regulation P,PI,PID... to maintain the position
   - it should be pretty straightforward
   - for example motors in x group with P (proportional regulation)
   - `thrust_x = c0 + c1 * (object_x-wanted_x)`
   - where `c1` is response constant play with it to achieve wanted response
   - too big will cause oscilations
   - too small will cause slow reactions
   - `c0` is anihilating external force fields like gravity
   - both `c0,c1` are dependent on the group strength, object mass,...
3. if you need also to control orientation

   - then you just have to add more groups

[notes]

- the motors usage can change with time (object can rotate)
- so you can convert the desired position to object local coordinate system
- or recompute the groups once in a while